# save to DB (mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a method that will store strings into a DB. However, my parameters don't seem to "exist in the current" context. I do have system.IO declared by the way but I still cannot get the code to recognize the parameters. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
[HttpPost]
    public void SaveAccount(string accountId, string AccountName, string Address, string City, string State, string ZipCode, string PhoneNumber, string IsActive) 
    public PartialViewResult SaveAccount(FormCollection form)
    {
        string accountid = form["SaveAccount"].ToString();

        using (OdbcConnection _conn = new OdbcConnection("FILEDSN=c:\\datasources\\RxCard.dsn"))
        using (OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand())
        {
            cmd1.Connection = _conn;
            cmd1.CommandText = "{call web.SaveAccount(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountID", accountId);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", AccountName);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", City);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", State);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipCode", ZipCode);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", IsActive);  // need to handle conversion from string to boolean on stored proc

            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", form["AccountName"].ToString());
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", form["Address"].ToString());
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", form["City"].ToString());
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", form["State"].ToString());
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipCode", form["ZipCode"].ToString());
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", form["PhoneNumber"].ToString());
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", form["IsActive"].ToString());  // need to handle conversion from string to boolean on stored proc
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            _conn.Open();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _conn.Close();
        }
```

The form:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAccount", "RxCard", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
                <div id="Edit">
                    <label id="lblAccountName">Account Name</label>
                    <input style="margin: 5px; " type=text name="txtAccountName" id="txtAccountName" value="@Model.Pharmacy.AccountName" />
                    <label id="lblAddress">Address</label>
                    <input style="margin: 5px; " type=text name="txtAddress" id="txtAddress" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Address" />
                    <label id="lblCity">City</label>
                    <input style="margin: 5px; " type=text name="txtCity" id="txtCity" value="@Model.Pharmacy.City" />
                    <label id="lblState">State</label>
                    <input style="margin: 5px; " type=text name="txtState" id="txtState" value="@Model.Pharmacy.State" />
                    <label id="lblZip">Zip</label>
                    <input style="margin: 5px; " type=text name="txtZip" id="txtZip" value="@Model.Pharmacy.ZipCode" />
                    <label id="lblPhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                    <input style="margin: 5px; " type=text name="txtPhoneNumber" id="txtPhoneNumber" value="@Model.Pharmacy.PhoneNumber" />
                </div>

                <div id="Add">

                </div>

                <div id="ChkBox">
                    <input id="chkIsActive" style="margin: 5px; " type="checkbox" name="chkIsActive" onchange='Areyousure(this)' value="@Model.Pharmacy.IsActive" @(Model.Pharmacy.IsActive =="True" ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") /> Is Active
                </div>

                <br/>
                <button type="submit" name="EditAccount" id="EditAccount" value="Edit">Edit</button>
                <button type="submit" name="SaveAccount" id="SaveAccount" value="@Model.Pharmacy.AccountID">Save</button>
               // <button type="submit" name="AddAccount" id="AddAccount" value="Add">Add</button>

                 }
```

Comment: What does the form that you are posting to this action look like? Additionally, if you are passing your parameters in, you can consider using the appropriate parsing types to convert the values before passing them in (e.g. `Convert.ToBoolean(form["IsActive"])`, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, The form is included above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` attribute is going to be the attribute that handles mapping key/values when the `<form>` is posted, so you'll need to adjust these to match what is present in your form (i.e. `txtAccountName` instead of `AccountName`):

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName",form["txtAccountName"]);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address",form["txtAddress"]);
// Other string parameters omitted for brevity
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", Convert.ToBoolean(form["chkIsActive"]));
```

It's worth noting that MVC will not automatically persist values for you, so the only values that will be present in your Controller Action will be those that have been either explicitly stored ahead of time (in something like `TempData`, a database or the Session) and the values that were posted in your form itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also get an error after : "string IsActive)". Visual studio suggests adding a ; but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Which line is that referring to?

Comment: The syntax for that Action doesn't look right at all. I don't currently see a body that corresponds to it. You may want to consider building a single class that contains all of your properties and their appropriate name values and populating everything that you need within the form and using a single `public ... SaveAccount(YourModel model);` action that handles everything that you need. .NET will map the appropriate values to the model or to any parameters that match the `name` attributes exactly.